# GNU module load before loading python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-modules

On a server I am working on, I need to run the following commands to ensure the `xlsxwriter` is available to import from python:

```
module load swdev
module load python/xlsxwriter_py3.4.2/0.7.2
```

However, I would like this to be done automatically when the python script that needs it is run, from within the python script. Running `os.system` or `subprocess.call` doesn't work. How do I do this?

Comment: Why os.system doesn't work? Could you insert input?

Comment: do you have appropriate permissions, to run `module load`? What errors do you get if you run `subprocess.check_call('module load swdev'.split())`?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but `import xlsxwriter` doesn't work after I run the command

Answer (score 0):

You can call `module` from a Python script. The `module` command is provided by the environment-modules software, which also provides a `python.py` initialization script.

Evaluating this script in a Python script enables the `module` python function. If environment-modules is installed in `/usr/share/Modules`, you can find this script at `/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py`.

Following code enables `module` python function:

```
import os
exec(open('/usr/share/Modules/init/python.py').read())
```

Thereafter you can load your modules:

```
module('load', 'swdev')
module('load', 'python/xlsxwriter_py3.4.2/0.7.2')
```